# VBScript Error code 800A0409, Unterminated string constant, on line 1

Tags: vbscript

I'm getting Error code 800A0409, Unterminated string constant, on line 1, 54 with the code below.

```
Option Explicit

Dim ObjProgressMsg
Dim fso,objText,strVstup,strVystup,f,dtmVyt,dtmF,dDiff,fName,fExt,fShort,dtmAkt,tx,msgText
Dim strMessage,strWindowTitle,strTemp,wshShell,objTempMessage,strTempVBS


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objText = fso.GetFile("l:\bat\posledni.den")
strVstup = "l:\filefolder\"
strVystup = "l:\backup"

dtmVyt = objText.DateLastModified

msgText = "Some text about copying and renaming" & VbCrLf & "files, please wait..."

ProgressMsg msgText

For Each f In fso.GetFolder(strVstup).Files
    
    dtmF = f.DateLastModified
    
    dDiff = DateDiff("s", dtmF, dtmVyt)
    
    If dDiff < 0 Then
          ProgressMsg ""
          WScript.Echo f
    End If
    
Next

WScript.Echo "Some text about the task being finished."


    

Function ProgressMsg( strMessage )
' Written by Denis St-Pierre
' Displays a progress message box that the originating script can kill in both 2k and XP
' If StrMessage is blank, take down previous progress message box
' Using 4096 in Msgbox below makes the progress message float on top of things
' CAVEAT: You must have   Dim ObjProgressMsg   at the top of your script for this to work as described
    Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
    strTEMP = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%TEMP%" )
    If strMessage = "" Then
        ' Disable Error Checking in case objProgressMsg doesn't exists yet
        On Error Resume Next
        ' Kill ProgressMsg
        objProgressMsg.Terminate( )
        ' Re-enable Error Checking
        On Error Goto 0
        Exit Function
    End If
        strTempVBS = strTEMP + "\" & "Message.vbs"     'Control File for reboot

    ' Create Message.vbs, True=overwrite
    Set objTempMessage = fso.CreateTextFile( strTempVBS, True )
    objTempMessage.WriteLine( "MsgBox""" & strMessage & """, 4096, """ & "a_sp_rano" & """" )
    objTempMessage.Close

    ' Disable Error Checking in case objProgressMsg doesn't exists yet
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Kills the Previous ProgressMsg
    objProgressMsg.Terminate( )
    ' Re-enable Error Checking
    On Error Goto 0

    ' Trigger objProgressMsg and keep an object on it
    Set objProgressMsg = WshShell.Exec( "%windir%\system32\wscript.exe " & strTempVBS )

End Function
```

The script should show a msgbox while searching for files newer than last modified date of posledni.den file. Then once it finds a file it should close msgbox and echo the file it found.
It works just fine if I change this:

```
msgText = "Some text about copying and renaming" & VbCrLf & "files, please wait..."
```

to this:

```
msgText = "Some text about copying and renaming" & "files, please wait..."
```

Removal of VbCrLf seems to fix that error, just no line break is obviously happening. I can't figure out why it's behaving like that, what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs in the execution of the generated .vbs. What you do is:

```
>> msg1 = "A" & vbCrLf & "B"
>> code = "MsgBox """ & msg1 & """"
>> WScript.Echo code
>>
MsgBox "A
B"
>> Execute code
>>
Error Number:       1033
Error Description:  Unterminated string constant
```

What you should do:

```
>> msg1 = """A"" & vbCrLf & ""B"""
>> WScript.Echo msg1
>>
"A" & vbCrLf & "B"
>> code = "MsgBox " & msg1 & ", 4096"
>> WScript.Echo code
>>
MsgBox "A" & vbCrLf & "B", 4096
>> Execute code
>>
>> <-- no news are good news; message displayed
```

Comment: Perfect, I can see it now. These double quotes always get so confusing to me when they are stacked up. Thank you very much! :)